# Is it possible to upload and convert an .rtf file to a .gdoc from PHP web app?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a web app that takes user input and creates a nice .rtf document.  I then want to take this newly created document, upload it to google drive and convert it to a google document.  Is this doable from within my webapp using PHP?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible

Comment: @MarkBaker, could you point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't speak to doing it programmatically, but it certainly looks like a positive sign that it is possible:

From Google Drive's [support site](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2407404?hl=en):

> Compatible file types
>
> These are the file types that can be converted to a Google document,
>   spreadsheet, or presentation:
>
> For documents: .doc, .docx, .html, plain text (.txt), **.rtf**

Additionally, over on the [Google Drive SDK site](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app):

> An app registered with the Import option enabled in the Drive SDK
>   options in the Developers Console can import supported Google Doc
>   formats. This means that if a user selects Open with for a Google doc,
>   the app can convert it to a format that the app can handle.
>
> ```
> Google Doc Format | Conversion Format | Corresponding MIME type
> ===============================================================
> Documents         | HTML              | text/html
>                   | Plain Text        | text/plain
>                   | Rich text         | application/rtf
> ```

Considering the above, it looks like the method detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples) is game to accept and convert .rtf files POSTed to your app's upload URI, so long as you set the `convert` query parameter to `true`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible to convert on upload from google drive's UI, but I am looking for a PHP solution to use with my webapp.

Comment: Check the final link I just edited the answer to include!

Comment: No prob! Good luck with the feature. :)